# Compiled with no Segmentation faults

Tags: c, linux

I was working with example from K&R, its a cat utility to view files

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(int argc,char **argv){
      FILE *fp;
      void filecopy(FILE *,FILE *);

      if(argc==1)
           filecopy(stdin,stdout);
      else                           // accidentally mistyped
           while(--argv > 0)         // should have been --argc > 0
                if((fp=fopen(*++argv,"r"))==NULL){
                        printf("cat: can't open %s\n",*argv);
                        return 1;
                }else{
                        filecopy(fp,stdout);
                        fclose(fp);
                }
     return 0;
}
void filecopy(FILE *ifp,FILE *ofp)
{
      int c;
      while((c=getc(ifp))!=EOF)
            putc(c,ofp);
}
```

When compiled with gcc cat.c,
and when I ran ./a.out cat.c from the terminal,all I got was some chinnesse symbols and some readable text(names like _fini_array_,_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ and etc..) and the garbage just went on until I pressed Ctrl+C, **I wanted to ask why I didn't got Segmentation fault**, because didn't the program was reading every memory location from argv start address? and I shouldn't have the rights to do so?

Comment: Didn't you just write out the contents of `argv[0]`, i.e., the executable itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at these two consecutive lines:

```
    while(--argv > 0)
            if((fp=fopen(*++argv,"r"))==NULL){
```

Every time you decrement `argv`, you end up incrementing it on the next line.  So overall, you are just decrementing and incrementing `argv` a lot but you are never actually reading past the bounds of the `argv` memory area.

Even if you were reading past the bounds of the `argv` memory area, that would be [undefined behavior](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213) and you are not guaranteed to get a segmentation fault.  The result you get depends on your compiler your, operating system, and the other things in your program.

I suspect that executing `--argv` also gives you undefined behavior, because after that line is executed, the pointer would probably point outside of the array allocated for `argv` data.  But, since you didn't dereference `argv` while it was pointing there, it turned out to be OK.

Comment: Also, moving argv back just means he got a filename from argv[0] instead of argv[1], and argv[0] just contains the program name.

Comment: OK, so his program is probably printing its own contents to stdout in an infinite loop.

Comment: so that means it executed the same as ./a.out a.out? If --argv now points to memory location argv-1 and then I increment it back with ++argv, now argv points to argv[0] again? which happens to be a.out

Comment: @simple16: Your program is just ignoring its arguments and printing its own contents to stdout repeatedly, but it also probably has some undefined behavior (due to executing `--argv`) so it is not guaranteed to do that every time on every computer.  So yes, running `./a.out` is equivalent to running `./a.out foobar` or `./a.out a.out` or `./a.out 1234`.